# Ubuntu 11.10 Wubi internet problems

Tags: wubi

I have Ubuntu 11.10 Wubi installed on a VM, and it has suddenly stopped being able to connect to the internet, it says connected, but the VM says there are no active IP addresses and it's not pingable... I have no idea whats causing this ... it's not the VM becuase Windows on the same VM works fine... Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Anything in your logs? Anything on the console? Anything more specific than "It doesn't work"? :-)

Comment: ubuntu says connected but when pinging I get network not available

Comment: Shot in the dark, do you have a gateway defined?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. how do you have wubi in a vm? are you saying your running a vm with windows that you then installed wubi on? So by extension you now have a dual boot vm of windows and ubuntu?

Comment: What VM (VMWare / Vbox), what host (windows, Ubuntu), and how did you configure the network (what type of virtual network card).

Comment: The usual VMWare ESXi 4, virtual NIC same NIC works fine when in windows, the problem seems to be in my ubuntu configuration, I only set it up a few days ago, also could it be something to do with the DNS, my ISPs DNS wasen't working so my friend set it to 8.8.8.8, maybe that's messing with something?

Comment: Yes @ Balloons.

Comment: Yes @ mastashake57

Comment: I've now installed a new IP and that's pingable, DNS isn't working though and not much else will connect

Comment: The problem turned out to be the datacenter network .. as I was using a different network for the vhost and the vm, switched to a new network and all is good again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a question for Server Fault :P the problem was the network, not quite sure what is wrong with it but it works in Windows and not Linux, anyway I used another network and it's working just fine. :)